# Ошибка JSONDecodeError при добавлении значения в json файл

Tags: python, json

Есть json файл:

```
{
    "one": [
        "one one",
        "one two",
        "one three"
    ],
    "two": [
        "two one",
        "two two",
        "two three"
    ],
    "three": [
        "three one",
        "three two",
        "three three"
    ]
}
```

В который нужно **добавить ключ с пустым списком**, для этого был написан код:

```
# !/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json

with open("test.json", 'a+', encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    bd = json.load(f)

    bd_add = {"four": []}
    bd.update(bd_add)
```

Но мне выдает ошибку:

```
JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)')
```

Насколько я понимаю, эта ошибка возникает при чтении файла json, возможно ему что-то не нравится в самом json, но я не понимаю что.

Как мне **добавить ключ с пустым списком** в файл json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import json

with open("n.json", 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
    bd = json.load(f)  # Чтение данных из, открытого на чтение, файла

bd_add = {"four": []}  # Формирование нового элемента
bd.update(bd_add)      # Добавление записи json

with open("n.json", 'w', encoding="utf8") as f:
    json.dump(bd, f)   # Запись данных в файл, открытый на запись
```

Comment: Но всё же лучше пояснять код текстом с его сутью

Comment: Добавил комментарии

Comment: Суть в том, что нужно переписать файл целиком, это и надо было написать текстом до кода или после. А комментарии "здесь мы А складываем с Б" особого смысла не имеют )